# What kind of button does DatePicker and ComboBox use?

Tags: javafx

I have been trying to find the button that DatePicker and ComboBox uses. I have searched through ComboBoxBase, and all other similar classes, and have been unable to find it. Is there a public version of this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `ComboBoxButton` class or public method that creates such a thing. You can try to reproduce what's done in the specific controls by referring to the source code.

The look of the JavaFX controls are defined in their skin classes; so `ComboBoxBaseSkin` for `ComboBox`, with some supporting classes for the popup and list view that's displayed inside the popup. For the most part, the skin class defines the layout and behavior (i.e. response to user input), and the actual look (shape of the arrow, colors, etc) is defined by the CSS file.

These buttons are defined in a pretty non-trivial way; for `ComboBox` the arrow itself is defined as a `Region`, which is placed inside the `arrowButton`, which is a `StackPane`. Then the CSS file defines the shape of the arrow and different colors and borders depending on whether it's pressed, selected, etc.

The source for JavaFX is available via OpenJFX:

- [Home](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/tree/master/modules)
- [`ComboBoxBaseSkin`](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/skin/ComboBoxBaseSkin.java)
- [`modena.css`](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css)

In the CSS file, I would search for `combo-box` (there's a couple of dozen occurrences), and pay particular attention to the `.arrow-button` and `.arrow` classes.